# Bin packing with amount limitation(Online)

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-mathematics

This is the problem:

For those who don't know Bin Packing: We get online input of 1 item each time with size in (0,1].
We use First-Fit. (As the name suggests, we put each item we get in the first available bin, so that the total size of the items in a bin won't be more than 1.)

The only limitations we have are:

- No bin can exceed $1$.
- No bin can hold more then $K$ items.

I need to prove that for any given $K$, the competitive ratio ("First_fit/Opt," meaning "First-Fit/Optimal") is less than or equal to 3.

I  tried to do it using induction:

Our premiss is that for any given $K$, the competitive ratio is less than 3.

If we check for $K=1$, we get ratio of $1<3$.

Let's use our premiss, and check if it works for $K=K+1$.

If we add more slot for each bin, the FF algorithm can only improve (since more might get into less bins), but the problem is that OPT might also improve.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Edit:

An example of FF vs. OPT:
For an input of $K=3$:

$\epsilon*3,1/3+\epsilon,1/3+\epsilon,1/3+\epsilon,1/3+\epsilon,1/2+\epsilon,1/2+\epsilon,1/2+\epsilon$

FF will do:
$(\epsilon*3)  , (1/3+\epsilon*2),(1/3+\epsilon*2),(1/2+\epsilon),(1/2+\epsilon),(1/2+\epsilon),(1/2+\epsilon)$

$7$ bins.

OPT will do:
$(1/2+\epsilon,1/3+\epsilon,\epsilon),(1/2+\epsilon,1/3+\epsilon,\epsilon),(1/2+\epsilon,1/3+\epsilon,\epsilon),(1/2+\epsilon,1/3+\epsilon)$

$4$ bins.

So for this example the ratio is $7/4$.

Comment: I think this is an interesting problem, but I'm afraid you might get some negative feedback due to formatting. For examples I suggest you fix some typos (e.g.: a comma should be followed by a white space) and be more explicit (e.g.: "First_first/Opt" meaning "First-**Fit**/Optimal") and use Mathjax properly (e.g.: K=1 should be $K=1$). Having said that, if after a few weeks no one responds, you can try the [cs site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) which you already registered.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin thank you for your kind feedback, any idea on the problem itself?

Comment: I don't understand the setting. You have a bunch of bins, each of which can hold up to a total size of $1$ but also only up to $K$ items. You have a first-fit algorithm for filling the bins with items...how many items? how big? how many bins can you use? And you compare this first-fit algorithm to the optimal fitting...optimal in what metric? The total number of bins used?

Comment: @Ian the classic approach in those kind of problems, is to try to minimize the number of bins you end up using. Given some items, the first-fit algorithms will end up using some number of bins. An "optimal" arrangement of items will use the minimum necessary number of bins. The efficiency of a greedy algorithm like first-fit is often measured by the ratio between the number of bins it yield, and the optimal number of bins. The question is about how to prove this ratio is less than 3.

Comment: And this is given a totally arbitrary input of bins, so the estimate is uniform in the input?

Comment: @Ian This is for any arbitrary (but fixed) input of **items**. Say you have some input of items $\mathrm{IN}$, first-fit algorithms yields a number $\mathrm{ff}(\mathrm{IN})$ of bins to use. Say the optimal arrangement of items/bins uses $\mathrm{opt}(\mathrm{IN})$ bins. The proof is to show that for any input $\mathrm{IN}$ you have $\mathrm{ff}(\mathrm{IN}) < 3 \times\mathrm{opt}(\mathrm{IN})$.

Comment: Items, yes, sorry, that's what I meant. Now I understand the setting, thank you.

Comment: @Ian added an example...
any idea guys?

Comment: It seems like a really bad input would be $KN$ $\epsilon$'s followed by $N$ $(1-K\epsilon)$'s (where $\epsilon < 1/K$ but otherwise arbitrary). Then first fit fills $2N$ bins while opt fills only $N$ bins. How can things be any worse than that for first fit? (Actual question, not rhetorical.)

Comment: @Ian well there is, for a matter of fact I found a way to get 2.25, but what you said isn't a proof , its an example, I need to show that there is no more then 3.

Comment: I know I gave an example, I'm trying to see how things get bad, intuitively. Because when $K=\infty$ the bound on the ratio is $2$, which follows because first-fit will always ensure that the total size in each bin is at least $1/2$. One would hope that there would be some simple intuition for the $K<\infty$ case too, which would presumably be illuminated by some example that attains the bound, or perhaps approaches the bound.

Comment: If I read the example correctly, FF uses 7 bins, not 9.

Comment: @Ian Actually I can't even come up with an example in the case $K=\infty$ that would reach the bound of $2$. The case $K<\infty$ has two things that can make you waste bins. 1: Stacking small items in one bin until it contains $K$ items, with a lot of free space remaining. 2: Similar to $K=\infty$, badly arranging items, (without reaching the $K$ limit,) resulting in a weight/capacity limitation on bins.

Comment: @N.Bach The example I've seen for the case $K=\infty$ consists of $2n$ repetitions of $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2n}$.  OPT sets aside all the small items and packs them all in one bin, for a total of $n+1$ bins, whereas FF packs $2n$ bins.  In the limit, you get the ratio of $2$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Hmm, if I get your example properly, FF actually packs $n+1$ bins. Some bin get a $\frac 12$ and start to get filled with small items too, until it is eventually full with one $\frac 12$ item and $n$ small items. With two such bins, you exhaust the small items, and the remaining large items fully fill $n-1$ bins, for a total of $n+1$. Also after digging a bit, it seems the $K=\infty$ bound for FF is actually 1.7, as is discussed [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70738/). It is probably possible to show the bound for $K<\infty$ should be 2.7 or something.

Comment: @N.Bach You are right about 1.7.  I was careless.  The ratio of $2$ is for *Next Fit*.  I was careless. Thanks for the link.  I looked up a paper by David Johnson yesterday, but it only had a reference to the  proof of the tighter bound. The problem with a $K < \infty$ tight bound is that it's not clear that the two limiting factors ("the bin is full," "the bin has too many items") can be made to cooperate to push up the bound.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi On the other hand, I think this question is not *really* asking for a tight bound. The desired bound can be proved with fairly blunt methodology, similar to the idea on the wiki page for the $K=\infty$ case.

Comment: @Ian Agreed.  My comment addressed N.Bach's observation that the bound for $K < \infty$ should be 2.7 or something, which I believe is true if stated as "a tight bound should be at most 2.7."  So, just a small friendly amendment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got some inspiration after looking at the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#First-fit_algorithm) for a bit.
The property used to prove the bound in the case $K=\infty$ is that you can never have two bins (or more) in the first-fit approach, that are less than half full. The second "less than half full" bin should never be created since the items it contains should first get put into the first "less than half full" bin. This yields an inequality that eventually yields the bound.

In the present case of $K<\infty$, the property should be rephrased into: there can never be two bins (or more) that contain strictly less than $K$ items, and that are less than half full.

Say you have $n$ items of weight $w_i$, $1\le i\le n$.
Say first-fit yields $A$ bins. Count the number of bins that contain the maximum number of items $K$, and let that number $A_1$. Let the number of remaining bins $A_2$, those bins can still accept new items and most of them should be at least half-full. Specifically,
$A_2-1 < 2\sum_{i=1}^n w_i$. Because $\sum_i w_i$ is a lower bound on the minimum number of bins $\mathrm{opt}$, you get $A_2-1<2\mathrm{opt}$. Since everyone is an integer, you can actually have $A_2\le 2 \mathrm{opt}$.

To complete the proof, you just notice that $A_1\le \frac nK \le\mathrm{opt}$.
When you put everything together you obtain
$A=A_1+A_2\le 3\mathrm{opt}$.